# backup script requires a pid lock to prevent multiple instances

Tags: bash, pid, lockfile

i have a bash script that runs daily rsync incremental backups.

my problem is i end up with multipul instances running. im new to bash scripts so im not sure if i have an issue in my script? posted below.

but i have read about a pid lockfile?

could anyone show me how i would go about adding this into my script?

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-     3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin


LinkDest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday

WeekDay=$(date +%A |tr [A-Z] [a-z])

echo "$WeekDay"

case $WeekDay in

    monday) 
    echo "Starting monday's backup"
    rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home  /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday --log- file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily.log
        ;;

    tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)
    echo "Starting inc backup : $WeekDay"   
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=$LinkDest /home     /home/backup/files/backupdaily/$WeekDay --log- file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily.log
        ;;

    sunday)    exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

so it looks like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-    3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

trap "rm -f /tmp/backup_daily_lockfile && exit" SIGINT SIGTERM #Put this on the top to   handle CTRL+C or SIGTERM

test -f /tmp/backup_daily_lockfile && exit #before rsync to ensure that the script will   not run if there is another one running

LinkDest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday

WeekDay=$(date +%A |tr [A-Z] [a-z])

echo "$WeekDay"
touch /tmp/backup_daily_lockfile #Before the rsync
case $WeekDay in

monday) 
echo "Starting monday's backup"
rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday --log-file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily.log
    ;;

tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)
echo "Starting inc backup : $WeekDay"   
rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=$LinkDest /home /home/backup/files/backupdaily/$WeekDay --log-file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily.log
        ;;

    sunday)    exit 0
        ;;

rm -f /tmp/backup_daily_lockfile #After the rsync

esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your script:

```
trap "rm -f /tmp/lockfile && exit" SIGINT SIGTERM #Put this on the top to handle CTRL+C or SIGTERM
test -f /tmp/lockfile && exit #Before rsync to ensure that the script will not run if there is another one running

touch /tmp/lockfile #Before the rsync

rm -f /tmp/lockfile #After the rsync
```

rename the lock file path/name according to your needs, you can also name it with the current PID using $$ variable.

Comment: Yes exactly like this ;)

Comment: hmmm i get this error

# sh /usr/local/src/backup/backup_daily_v3.sh
wednesday
/usr/local/src/backup/backup_daily_v3.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `-f'
/usr/local/src/backup/backup_daily_v3.sh: line 30: `rm -f /tmp/backup_daily_lockfile #After the rsync'

Comment: @Kevin the script exactly as you posted in your question ?

Comment: Can you paste line 30 here in a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution has a race condition. If two instances are running at approximately the same time, they could both execute the `test` before either of them gets to the `touch`. Then they will end up overwriting each others' files after all.

The proper fix is to use an atomic test and set. A common and simple solution is to use a temporary directory instead, and exit if `mkdir` fails; otherwise, you have the lock.

```
# Try to grab lock; yield if unsuccessful
mkdir /tmp/backup_daily_lockdir || exit 1
# We have the lock; set up to remove on exit
trap "rmdir /tmp/backup_daily_lockdir" EXIT
# Also run exit trap if interrupted
trap 'exit 127' SIGINT SIGTERM

: the rest of your script here
```

There are other common solutions, but this has no external dependencies and is very easy to implement and understand.

Comment: ok so how would i go about writing this method into my script?

Comment: Another possibility is to create a temporary file and attempt to `mv tempfile lockfile` - renaming is supposed to be atomic on at least most of the common file systems. It may not be universally guaranteed, though...